# How to give a list an id in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

**Hi,**

I'm new to Prolog programming.

**My questions is :**

Let's say I have this list of elements `[a,e,u,o,y,i]` 
and I want to give it an identifier, for example `vowels`.

**Why ?**

Let's say we have a defined predicate `member/2` that checks recursively if an element exists in a list and therefore our queries would be something like that :

```
    ?- member(x,vowels).
    false
    ?- member(a,vowels).
    true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really clear to me what you mean when you say "*I want to give it an identifier*"...

Why not define predicate `vowel/1` and use `vowel(X)` instead of `member(X,[a,e,u,o,y,i])`?

```
vowel(a).
vowel(e).
vowel(u).
vowel(o).
vowel(y).
vowel(i).
```

Sample uses:

```
?- vowel(x).
false.

?- vowel(a).
true.
```

Comment: That's doable for small data, but what if I'm dealing with huge list. And running this querry ``member(X,[a,e,u,o,y,i])``

Comment: Is that huge list unavoidable? An advantage of using a `vowel/1` predicate defined as a set of facts is the performance when checking if a letter is a vowel. Thanks to the first-argument indexing found in most Prolog systems, that check is O(1) while using a list is (in the worst case) O(n) where n is the number of elements in your huge list.

Comment: What is the utility of `member(e,[a,e,u,o,y,i])` since ,as we're writing this query, we can notice that `e` is a member of this list ? So I'm looking for way to "pass the list as an argument" to the "member" predicate without having to type every element of it .

Comment: In others words, I want to have a sequence of characters that refers to a given list, so I can refer to a whole list just by typing that sequence of characters. As a C++ user, we can refer to a vector of items just by typing its identifier, and once we have to manipulate this vector as a whole, we only type its identifiers. Is there a way to refer to a list [....] just by typing a sequence of characters? so I can run queries this way `member(element,list_id).` instead of `member(element,[...,element,...]).` cuz by typing the second query you can deduce that the element is a member.

Comment: @reaffer. There are two issues here. First, we do not want to construct said list `[a,...,u]` again and again for every "vowel"-test. Second, we do not want to run `member/2` for every test, as it has O(n) complexity. With above predicate `vowel/1` we achieve both: at compile-time, an internal read-only constant hash-table is constructed---at runtime that table is used over and over again for O(1) access. (The benefit gets more apparent for larger number of base-cases, e.g., if we store hundreds of, say, city names, not just a handful of vowels.)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define a predicate `vowels/1`:

```
vowels([a,e,u,o,y,i]).
```

And then write:

```
?- vowels(Vowels), member(x, Vowels).
false.
?- vowels(Vowels), member(a, Vowels).
Vowels = [a, e, u, o, y, i] .
```

If you don't the bindings that make the query true printed, as you hint in your comment, simply define a `vowel/1` predicate:

```
vowel(Letter) :-
    vowels(Vowels), member(Letter, Vowels).
```

Comment: `?- vowels(Vowels), member(a, Vowels).` is returning `Vowels = [a,e,u,o,y,i]`

Comment: Queries that succeed always return any bindings that make the query true. In some Prolog systems, e.g. YAP you can avoid printing bindings by using variables that start with an underscore, however. E.g. `vowels(_Vowels), member(a, _Vowels).`.

Comment: @repeat Also in B-Prolog, GNU Prolog, SICStus Prolog, and XSB.

Comment: @PauloMoura. I didn't know that! Cool feature. Just checked: SWI and ciao do it too.

Comment: @repeat It doesn't work for me with SWI-Prolog 7.3.9. Which version are you using?

Comment: SWI 7.3.8 after startup: `?- current_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_anon,X).
X = true.
?- _X = 1.
_X = 1.`
Later:
`?- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_anon,false).
true.

?- _X = 1.
true.`

Comment: @repeat Good catch. I completely forgot about the `toplevel_print_anon` flag. But is poorly named. Alas, the interpretation of variables that start with an underscore (other then the `_` anonymous variable) is a mess in Prolog with e.g. differences between a `_Foo` and a `_foo` when reporting singleton variables between systems.